# Printing out values of an Object using propertyDescriptors

Tags: javascript

**Problem:**
According https://javascript.info/property-descriptors
property descriptors are like objects with own properties like:

```
{
value:
writable:
readable:
configurable:
enumerable:
}
```

one can do this with normal object:

```
for(var n in object) {
console.log(object[n]);
}
```

to write out the values of the keys in that object.
I want to do the same. Get descriptors, then for each descriptor print the value.

This is one of several ways I tried to do it. For each of the Property Descriptor in descriptors, print out the value of its properties.

I imagined getting something like
"John Doe"
0
etc...

Basically, put in other words, using Descriptors to show the values stored within an object.

**Own tryes:**
I tryed several times, so many times and ways that I
actually forgot, had to delete to to keep my head somewhat clear from the clutter of previous tryes. It resulted in all kinds of imaginable output except of what I expected. like numbers: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4... names of the properties instead of their values, or rows of "undefined" whilst I was expecting something like
"John Doe"
0
function
function
10 etc...
I DID check stackoverflow, AND other pages as well.
http://speakingjs.com/es5/ch17.html#property_attributes
being just one of say, 3-4.
It is NOT a homework, Also I do belive its probably not the best practise in doing it this way, using descriptors, but I got frustrated and obsessed, because I feel it should be possible.
I also apologize for eventuall weirdness in code. Im new at Javascript. I hope people focus on the problem and not on other stuff. English isnt my first language. I DID try to make the code as short as possible, and replicable. Hopefully Its clear what I want to do, otherwise Ill probably just give up xD.

**Code**

```
"use strict";

function Person() {
  this._name = "";
  this.age = 0;
  this.greet = function() {
    console.log(`hi Im ${this._name} and im ${this.age} years old`);
  };
  this.beep = function(times) {
    for(var i = 0; i < times; i++) {
      console.log("beeeep");
    }
  };
  Object.defineProperty(this, "something", {
    value: 10,
    writable: false,
    readable: true,
    configurable: false,
    enumerable: true,

  });
  Object.defineProperty(this, "name", {
    get() {
      return this._name;
    },
    set(nam) {
      this._name = nam;
    }
  } );

}

var obj = new Person();
console.log(obj.something);
obj.name = "John Doe";
console.log(obj.name);
console.log("##############");

var properties = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(obj);
for(var property in properties) {
  for(var val in property) {
    console.log(property[val]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`property` is a *key* not a *value*, use that *key* to access the related *value* of the object:

```
 for(var property in properties) {
  for(var val in properties[property]) {
    console.log(property, val, properties[property][val]);
  }
}
```

Comment: This worked. Still find accessing keys and values a bit confusing xD. Also gonna have to check how the multi arg console.log version works :). Thanks dude :)

Answer (score 1):

`property` in your example at the end is a **string**, the name of the property in the object returned by `getOwnPropertyDescriptors`. You want the *value* of that property for your second loop:

```
var properties = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(obj);
for(var property in properties) {
  var descriptor = properties[property]; // ***
  for(var val in descriptor) {
  // *** --------^^^^^^^^^^
    console.log(property[val]);
  }
}
```

Or in a modern environment you'd probably use [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) or [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) instead:

```
const properties = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(obj);
for (const [propName, descriptor] of Object.entries(properties)) {
    console.log(`${propName}:`);
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(descriptor)) {
        console.log(`    ${key}: ${value}`);
    }
}
```

Live Example:

```js
"use strict";

function Person() {
  this._name = "";
  this.age = 0;
  this.greet = function() {
    console.log(`hi Im ${this._name} and im ${this.age} years old`);
  };
  this.beep = function(times) {
    for(var i = 0; i < times; i++) {
      console.log("beeeep");
    }
  };
  Object.defineProperty(this, "something", {
    value: 10,
    writable: false,
    readable: true,
    configurable: false,
    enumerable: true,

  });
  Object.defineProperty(this, "name", {
    get() {
      return this._name;
    },
    set(nam) {
      this._name = nam;
    }
  } );

}

var obj = new Person();
console.log(obj.something);
obj.name = "John Doe";
console.log(obj.name);
console.log("##############");

const properties = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(obj);
for (const [propName, descriptor] of Object.entries(properties)) {
    console.log(`${propName}:`);
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(descriptor)) {
        console.log(`    ${key}: ${value}`);
    }
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Own answer, Also clearly showing what I wanted to do

Apparently its almost encouraged to answer own questions.
What threw me off was that one sort of needs to "backreference" inside the for loops. (Perhaps due to learning Java before).

To get property value one needs to mention the object that contains it.

**descriptions**[property]

and to get what is inside that you need in turn write

**descriptions[property]**[whatever]

Anyways. If anyone wondered, heres the now working code, albeight with slightly different variable names. But then again, shorter and easyer to follow. Shows exactly what I was looking for :D

```
"use strict";

function User(name, age) {

  this.name = name;
  this.age = age;
  this.func = function() {
    console.log("hola");
  };

}

var person = new User("John Doe", 22);

var descriptors = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(person);

for(var property in descriptors) {
  console.log(property);
  for(var k in descriptors[property]) { //<-------------
    console.log(k + " " + descriptors[property][k]);//<-----------
  }
  console.log("_______________");
}
```

I denoted what I previously didnt get with arrows in the comments.

Comment: Not trying to steal T.J Crowders thunder. His working code pointed me into the right direction :D